# echo out random numbers 0.5 to 1?

Tags: php, mysql

hi i am trying to use php to echo out a random set of numbers from 0.5 all the way to 1; so 05, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 > 1

i am currently echoing out a list of users and so need these numbers to be echoed out with each user randomly.

is there an easy way to do this?

```
<?php
    $local_set = get_local_users();
    $local_count = mysql_num_rows($local_set);
    while ($local = mysql_fetch_array($local_set)) {

        echo "<div class=\"sugarushcase\">
        <a href=\"profile.php?id={$local['id']}\"><img width=80px height= 80px src=\"data/photos/{$local['id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"boxgrid\"/></a><div class=\"local_text\">about (RANDOM NUBER) mile</div>
        </div>";

    }
```

Comment: Your description of "random number" is so complex that it makes me wonder whether you actually want a sequence :-? And, do you code or the MySQL tag have anything to do with your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand):

```
$rand = mt_rand(5, 10) / 10;
```

You could calculate this random number for every iteration, right before `echo`, then use `$rand` instead of `(RANDOM NUMBER)` in your example.

Comment: thanks this works great, i've done it so that it's like this: $rand = mt_rand(4, 10) / 10; so the values are showing as 0.4/0.5 etc is there a way that i can get it so that if it is 1 to show as 1.0 rather than just 1?

Comment: @JamesPale, sure, take a look at [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format). You could use something like: `$rand = number_format($rand, 1)`;

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) to achieve this, passing in the min and max:

```
rand (5, 10) / 10
```

Your code would then be:

```
echo "<div class=\"sugarushcase\">
    <a href=\"profile.php?id={$local['id']}\"><img width=80px height= 80px" + 
    "src=\"data/photos/{$local['id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"boxgrid\"/></a><div class=\"local_text\">about" + 
    (rand (5, 10) / 10) + "mile</div></div>";
```

Comment: @JamesPale Added a usage :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, here is your edited code.

```
<?php
$local_set = get_local_users();
$local_count = mysql_num_rows($local_set);
$random_number = mt_rand (0.5*10, 1.0*10) / 10; //Edit min/max values here
while ($local = mysql_fetch_array($local_set)) {

    echo "<div class=\"sugarushcase\">
    <a href=\"profile.php?id={$local['id']}\"><img width=80px height= 80px src=\"data/photos/{$local['id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"boxgrid\"/></a><div class=\"local_text\">about {$random_number} mile</div>
    </div>";

}
```

It was written without being tested so comment if it doesn't work & I'll look into it :)